# How to close a window in Shopware backend in my Plugin

Tags: plugins, shopware

I have a Plugin where I can create a shipping label. After i created it the window closes with win.destroy(); which is fine and i get back to the window that was open before. I would like to know
if i can close the window i get to after creating my label when i m doing the action? So I would like to close both windows that were open before.
here is the code

```
saveDpdconflist: function(orderid,win) {
        var me = this;      
          
        dpdform = me.getDpdConf().getForm();                
        var dpdvalue = dpdform.getFieldValues();
        
        dpdtabform = me.getDpdtabConf().getForm();  
         if (!dpdtabform.isValid()) {
            Shopware.Notification.createGrowlMessage('',me.snippets.requireError,'');
            return;
        }
            
        var dpdtabvalue = dpdtabform.getFieldValues();      
        var newstore = Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Order.DxOrderDpdtab.store.Dxorderlabel');
        
        newstore.load({
            params: {
                        dxorderid: orderid,
                        dxsalutation: dpdvalue.salutation,

                        dxfirstname: dpdvalue.firstName,
                        dxlastname: dpdvalue.lastName,
                        dxcompany: dpdvalue.company,
                        dxdepartment: '',
                        dxstreet: dpdvalue.street,
                        dxstreetno: dpdvalue.streetNumber,
                        dxcity: dpdvalue.city,
                        dxzipcode: dpdvalue.zipCode,
                        dxcountry: dpdvalue.countryname,
                        dxphone: dpdvalue.phone,
                        dxdpdproduct: dpdtabvalue.dxdpdshipname,
                        dxlabelpos: dpdtabvalue.labelposition_cmbx,
                        dxexportdoc: '1',
                        dxpayment: '1',
                        dxnoofgenpdf: dpdtabvalue.anzahlaversand,
                        dxcodtext: dpdtabvalue.nachnahmereferenz,
                        dxbyhand: '0',
                        dxweight: '5',          
                        dxlblchgdpd: dpdvalue.dpdchngshipadd,           
                        dxemail: dpdvalue.email,            
                        dxshipdate: dpdtabvalue.from_date,          
                        dxparcelshopid: win.record.raw.dxparcelshopid,

                    },        
                    callback: function(data, operation) {
                        var records = operation.getRecords(),
                        record = records[0],
                        rawData = record.getProxy().getReader().rawData;
                        
                        if(operation.success === true && rawData.data.error == '') {
                            
                            if(rawData.data.number == '1'){
                                if(rawData.data.retoureOption == 1){
                                    url = "{url controller='DxOrderDpdtab' action='getExportPDF'}";
                                    url = url+'/id/'+(rawData.data.id-1);
                                    window.open(url,'_blank');
                                }
                                url = "{url controller='DxOrderDpdtab' action='getExportPDF'}";
                                url = url+'/id/'+rawData.data.id;
                                window.open(url,'_blank');
                            }
                            
                            Shopware.Notification.createGrowlMessage(me.snippets.successTitle,me.snippets.labelSuccessMessage,me.snippets.growlMessage);
                            win.destroy();
                        } 
                        else{
                            Shopware.Notification.createGrowlMessage(me.snippets.failureTitle,rawData.data.error,me.snippets.growlMessage);
                        }
                    }
        });

        
    },
```

Comment: I assume this is about Shopware 5? would be nice, if you could state this clearly in the title next time ;-)

Comment: yes sorry it s shopware 5